# Put constrains to an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edit text and I'd like to put the following constrains (in the XML code if possible):

- Disable all the capital Letters (the inverse of android:capitalize or the same fonction than toLowerCase())
- Block to EditText to 1 line max. (for instance avoid that when I press enter the editText
  get bigger to create a new line)

In fact , my editText is a Search Field (but in my case I don't want to use the special Search Widget).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the edittext single line add this to its tag:

```
  android:singleLine="true"
```

Also android:capitalize is depreciated and the following should be used instead

```
  android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

However there seems to be no matching lowercase inputType, so you may have to implement it manually using a setOnKeyListener.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:lines="1"` in the android xml page and then see the layout.